# Method not found: '!!0 System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Byte>, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)'

Tags: exception, serialization, methods

Just tried to create a new web api .net 6.0 and on first build/run getting error:

1>obj\Debug\net6.0\staticwebassets.build.json : error : MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(System.ReadOnlySpan`1, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)'.
[image]

Any Idea?!

Comment: looks like that is a windows update issue, i created new project in a different pc and works fine. i took a look and my pc is updated. really need help with that issue...

Comment: I ran into the same problem, just update Visual Studio to 17.5.0 Preview 5.0.

Comment: I have exactly this error using MassTransit. System.Text.Json is installed in 8.0.0 version, do not have a clue how to solve it, maybe someone has a tip how to move forward?